# Stuck getting For Loop to execute right on the first iteration

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I have tried several variations of the following if statement without any luck. I'm sure it is a simple mistake.

Here is the code -

```
this.params = function (request) {
    var queryParams;
    queryParams = request.urlQuery;
    var fragments = queryParams.split('&');
    return {
        "has_query_parameters": true,
        "query_parameters": (function () {
            var results;
            results = [];
            if (queryParams.length != 0) {
                for (i in fragments) {
                    var keyvalue = fragments[i].split('=')
                    name = keyvalue[0];
                    if (i === 1) {
                        results.push(keyvalue[0] + '=" & ' + '$' + keyvalue[0]);
                    } else {
                        results.push('&' + keyvalue[0] + '=" & ' + '$' + keyvalue[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return results.join(" & \"");
        })()
    };
};
```

For the If statement where it says `i === 1` is where the issue is. What I need to happen is have that execute if it is the first fragment. Everything I have tried so far has failed and it executes the else instead.

Here is the queryParams variable:

```
client_id=CLIENTIDHERE&response_type=code&scope=SCOPESHERE&redirect_uri=REDIRECTURIHERE&state=STATEHERE
```

Comment: You may want to consider using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). You haven't stated what you're trying to achieve, but I know from experience parsing URLs is a wheel many times re-invented

Comment: Not sure if for (I in fragments) is valid code in JS. However, assuming it is, theoretically wouldn't i be the first fragment in the array, not a number?

Comment: What is happening is the return is starting with a & which means the if ( i === 1 )  is not executing on the first iteration through the fragments and is returning an & and the beginning of the return which is not desired.

Comment: This is what I am trying to achieve - for a result from the return.  client_id=" & $client_id & "&response_type=" & $response_type & "&scope=" & $scope & "&redirect_uri=" & $redirect_uri & "&state=" & $state  However what I am getting is &client_id=" & $client_id & "&response_type=" & $response_type & "&scope=" & $scope & "&redirect_uri=" & $redirect_uri & "&state=" & $state

Comment: So essentially what I need to determine with that if statement is if I have the first fragment from queryParams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays start at `0`. You want your condition to read: `i === 0` to match the first query parameter fragment.

**Update:**

It looks like your keys (`i`) are strings. You will need to use `parseInt(i) === 0` if you are going to use an identity comparison. Otherwise, `i == 0` should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too. I thought that was the issue but that did not work.